# converting any number system to binary an essential question.

Tags: number-theory

Why we write the remainder bottom to up from converting any number system to 
binary? We can write it from up to down, why not? And what is the logic here?

Comment: Please can you explain what method you are referring to?

Comment: It is not in the least bit clear what you are talking about.  Please redo this question entirely.

Comment: You should try the method you're thinking of with the first 10 or 12 integers, and you'll probably see why it works the way it does. Notice what happens with a number like 6.

Comment: We use the same method for binary that we use for base 10.  We could have in the beginning of time changed how we write numbers to go in the opposite order so that instead of writing $4*100 + 3*100 + 2*10 + 1 = 4321$ we would write $4*1000 + 3*100 + 2*10 + 1 = 1234$.  But we didn't.  Why didn't we?  No-one knows.  No-one cares.  But we didn't.  So we do binary in the *EXACT* same way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number written in binary and you want to know if it's even or odd, how do you tell?  You look at the rightmost digit, don't you?  Now when you convert some number to binary, the remainder of the first division tells you whether it's even or odd, right?  So do you want to write it on the left or the right?  On the right, of course.  Put it where you would look for it!